# Regex: Why does "part3(?=[\_$"])" not match "part1_part2_part3"?

Tags: regex

I can't figure out why this regex won't work (https://regexr.com/4od1b):

```
part3(?=[\_$])
```

Using this positive lookahead I would guess, that this should match `part1_part2_part3` but it doesn't. On the other hand, it matches `part1_part2_part3_part4` as expected.

Why doesn't this work? I want to match part3 EITHER being at the end of the string or being followed by a "_".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work? I want to match part3 EITHER being at the end of the string or being followed by a "_".

You should be using this regex:

```
part3(?=[_"]|$)
```

and make sure `m` (multiline) and `g` (global) flags are turned on.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regexr.com/4od20)

PS: `$` inside `[...]` is a literal `$` not end of line anchor.